# Find key word exactly from a text field in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula below:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Perso",$A2))
```

I want to it return **True** for the field that exactly contains my key word "**Perso**"

[image]

However, from the image you can see that both rows return True, because the word "*person*" also contains "*perso*".

Can anyone provide some suggestions on how can I achieve my goal in Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the deliminating space:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" Perso "," " & $A2 & " "))
```

[image]

Comment: I liked the adding of the spaces to the source cell

Comment: Technically speaking if they are looking for an EXACT match, shouldn't the search be case sensitive?

Comment: To make it case sensitive you can  use `FIND` instead of `SEARCH`

Comment: Yes, search is not case sensitive.